# How to override Distance evaluation Method of Kmeans algorithm

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

I have requirement of overriding Kmeans's distance evaluation algorithm of spark framework. I don't want to implement Euclidean distance calculation method but want to customize it.How can i override it ?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is unfortunately no way to provide a custom distance function to Apache Spark's mllib implementation of K-Means.

There are a couple of options for you if you're willing to move away from the mllib implementation though. One is [Apache Math Commons' implementation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/ml/clustering/KMeansPlusPlusClusterer.html) of the K-Means algorithm which allows you to supply your own distance function as one of the constructor arguments.

There exists as well a Scala native library called [Nak](https://github.com/scalanlp/nak) which provides its own [implementation](https://github.com/scalanlp/nak/blob/master/src/main/scala/nak/cluster/Kmeans.scala). Nak's implementation also allows you to supply your own distance function and is also parametrized on any type `T` and so might save you a little bit of inconvenience in translating types back and forth if you're using Spark extensively. Unfortunately Nak appears to suffer from some maintenance issues as using it will lock you into a rather old version of Scala Breeze (0.9 vs the current 0.12), which may or may not be an issue for you.